# Write spark Dataframe to an exisitng Delta Table by providing TABLE NAME instead of TABLE PATH

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, delta-lake

I am trying to write spark dataframe into an existing delta table.

I do have multiple scenarios where I could save data into different tables as shown below.

**SCENARIO-01:**

I have an existing delta table and I have to write dataframe into that table with option `mergeSchema` since the schema may change for each load.

I am doing the same with below command by providing delta table **path**

```py
finalDF01
  .write
  .format("delta")
  .option("mergeSchema", "true")
  .mode("append")
  .partitionBy("part01","part02")
  .save(finalDF01DestFolderPath)
```

Just want to know whether this can be done by providing exisiting delta **TABLE NAME** instead of delta **PATH**.

This has been resolved by updating data write command as below.

```py
finalDF01
  .write
  .format("delta")
  .option("mergeSchema", "true")
  .mode("append")
  .partitionBy("part01","part02")
  .saveAsTable(finalDF01DestTableName)
```

1. Is this the correct way ?

**SCENARIO 02:**

I have to update the existing table if the record already exists and if not insert a new record.
For this I am currently doing as shown below.

```py
spark.sql("SET spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled = true") 
DeltaTable.forPath(DestFolderPath)
   .as("t")
   .merge(
      finalDataFrame.as("s"),
         "t.id = s.id AND t.name= s.name")
       .whenMatched().updateAll()
       .whenNotMatched().insertAll()
   .execute()
```

I tried with below script.

```py
destMasterTable.as("t")
      .merge(
         vehMasterDf.as("s"),
          "t.id = s.id")
       .whenNotMatched().insertAll()
       .execute()
```

but getting below error(even with `alias` instead of `as`).

```
error: value as is not a member of String
    destMasterTable.as("t")
```

2. Here also I am using delta table path as destination, Is there any way so that we could provide delta **TABLE NAME** instead of **TABLE PATH**?

It will be good to provide TABLE **NAME** instead of TABLE **PATH**, In case if we chage the table path later will not affect the code.
I have not seen anywhere in databricks documentation providing table name along with `mergeSchema` and `autoMerge`.
Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use existing data as a table instead of path you either were need to use `saveAsTable` from the beginning, or just register existing data in the Hive metastore using the SQL command [CREATE TABLE USING](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-using.html), like this (syntax could be slightly different depending on if you're running on Databricks, or OSS Spark, and depending on the version of Spark):

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table
USING delta
LOCATION 'path_to_existing_data'
```

after that, you can use `saveAsTable`.

For the second question - it looks like `destMasterTable` is just a `String`.  To refer to existing table, you need to use function `forName` from the `DeltaTable` object ([doc](https://docs.delta.io/latest/api/scala/io/delta/tables/DeltaTable$.html)):

```scala
DeltaTable.forName(destMasterTable)
  .as("t")
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks very much . This is what actually  I was searching for.

Comment: Did not see these options in the databricks documentation though.